# Rediscover method of calculation Subnet

Tags: ipv4, subnet

I am preparing for my CCENT exam and about 3-4 month ago, I had found a method of calculating subnet. Unfortunately I did not bookmark the site and i forgot how to do it.

All I remember is how you start.

You first build that table.

0_____1

1_____2

2_____4

3_____8

4_____16

5_____32

6_____64

7_____128

8_____256

9_____512

10____1024

11____2048

12____4096

There is a 3rd column that you start from the middle after you are done with the first 2.

I dont remember where it starts.

If someone have seen this way of doing it and can explain it properly or link to the site that suggest this method.

Thank you

Benoit Bourgault

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the kind of table you're referring to:

[image: subnet quick ref]

It came from site: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/ip-subnetting-made-easy-125343/